# Shorten MySQL SELECT with RegExp

Tags: mysql, regex, select

In my db I have phone numbers like 094-144-54
But  I have to find them only with 09414454

Right now I've got this:

```
0[^[:digit:]]*9[^[:digit:]]*4[^[:digit:]]*1[^[:digit:]]*4[^[:digit:]]*4[^[:digit:]]*5[^[:digit:]]*4
```

It works, but is there a shorter way to write this? I know \D but I think it doesn't work with the MySQL RegtExp implementation.

Also, how do I select several rows like this?

```
SELECT number FROM tb1 WHERE ((number REGEXP ' ... '), (number REGEXP ' ... '), ... );
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "from several rows?"  Do you want to use `AND`/`OR`?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this a pure digit number starting with 0 and ended by 4:

```
SELECT number FROM tb1 WHERE (number REGEXP '^0[[:digit:]]*4$');
```

Or a pure digit number as this:

```
SELECT number FROM tb1 WHERE (number REGEXP '^[[:digit:]]+$');
```

This php to reform an input string "09414454":

```
<?php
$strPhoneNo = "09414454";
$strPhoneNo = substr(chunk_split($strPhoneNo, 3, '\-'), 0, -2);
//
// => "094\-144\-54"
//
$strSQL = "SELECT number FROM tb1 WHERE (number REGEXP '^$strPhoneNo$');";
//
echo "<pre>\n";
echo $strSQL;
echo "</pre>\n";
//
// $strSQL:
// SELECT number FROM tb1 WHERE (number REGEXP '^094\-144\-54$');
//...
?>
```

Comment: This works for pure digit numbers, but I need to select from numbers with special characters between the digits.

Comment: Please clarify this "But I have to find them only with 09414454" ?

Comment: For example, I've got the string '09414454' and have to find the db entry with the number/string '094-144-54' without using any ID or something

Comment: You got the string '09414454' in PHP, ASP, JSP, ... ?

Comment: in PHP. I tried something with "WHERE" and "in" but I can't figure out how to make it work